# Python file to exe not working in all locations in my computer only works in dist folder in python installation

Tags: python, exe, py2exe

I have created an `exe` file from `python` file which is  `add.py` in my case,
I followed this tutorial [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3VoLjGA6jI)

My setup.txt file as follows:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['add.py'])
setup(options = { "py2exe": {"includes": ["encodings"]}})
```

The following is my exe creation step:

[image: exe creation CMD]

I got output `exe` file which is `add.exe` in this location `C:\Python34\dist`. I double clicked it and it is working. When I move that add.exe to another location suppose `C:\Python34` or Any other location in my system it is not working. It is giving the following error instead of executing:

[image]

I do not have any idea why it is misbehave like this way. I need that exe file to work all my locations. How can I solve this? Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setup(
    console=['add.py'], 
    options = { 
        "py2exe": {
              "includes": ["encodings"], 
              "bundle_files": 1, 
              "ascii": False
         }
    }, 
    zipfile = None
)
```